# Why am I receiving an Undefined Index error when using AJAX/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xampp

I am currently working on a telecontrol application in which I am trying to send joystick coordinates from Javascript to PHP. However, I am never able to access the data via the PHP file as I get an Undefined Index error.

I am aware that this question has been addressed many times, but I have spent the past week going through forums and Google and none of the solutions I have tried have worked, so I would appreciate it if someone could take a look at my code to see if I have some fundamental misunderstanding or application-specific problem.

EDIT: I forgot to mention this earlier, but I had tried some example PHP/AJAX code that others have posted online, and running that code did not work either, which makes me think that maybe this is a problem with my server configuration.

My Code: (Only includes files I believe to be relevant to the problem; if you would like to see the other files in the project, plase let me know.)
The JavaScript and PHP files are in the same directory. I am using XAMPP.

**joystick.js** (Contains ajax call)

```
var hasGP = false;
var repGP;

// Joystick State Variables
var triggerPressed;
var x_value;
var y_value;
var z_value;
var t_value;

function canGame() 
{
    return "getGamepads" in navigator;
}

function reportOnGamepad() 
{
    // Display the gamepad's ID.
    var gp = navigator.getGamepads()[0];
    var html = "";
    html += "<u>ID</u>: " + gp.id + "<br>";

    // Display the status of the x-axis.
    x_value = gp.axes[0];
    html += "<u>x-axis</u>: " + x_value + "<br>";

    // Display the status of the y-axis.
    trigger_pressed = gp.buttons[0].pressed;
    y_value = gp.axes[1];
    if (trigger_pressed)
    {
        html += "<u>Pitch angle</u>: " + y_value + "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        html += "<u>y-axis</u>: " + y_value + "<br>";
    }

    // Display the status of the z-axis.
    z_value = gp.axes[3];
    html += "<u>z-axis</u>: " + z_value + "<br>";

    // Display the status of the t-axis.
    t_value = gp.axes[2];
    html += "<u>Roll angle</u>: " + t_value + "<br>";

    $("#gamepadDisplay").html(html);

    $.ajax({ url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {x:x_value},
        success: function(data) 
        {
            console.log("x_value " + data + " has been sent to the  server.");
        }
    });

}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    if(canGame()) 
    {
        var prompt = "To begin using your gamepad, connect it and press any button!";
        $("#gamepadPrompt").text(prompt);

        $(window).on("gamepadconnected", function() 
        {
            hasGP = true;
            $("#gamepadPrompt").html("<b>The gamepad has been successfully connected.</b><br><br>");
            console.log("connection event");
            repGP = window.setInterval(reportOnGamepad,100);
        });

        $(window).on("gamepaddisconnected", function() 
        {
            console.log("disconnection event");
            $("#gamepadPrompt").text(prompt);
            window.clearInterval(repGP);
        });

        // Set up an interval for Chrome
        var checkGP = window.setInterval(function() 
        {
            console.log('checkGP');
            if(navigator.getGamepads()[0]) 
            {
                if(!hasGP) $(window).trigger("gamepadconnected");
                window.clearInterval(checkGP);
            }
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

**ajax.php** (File to which Javascript data should be sent)

```
<?php
    $temp = $_POST['x'];
    if(isset($temp) && !empty($temp))
    {
        echo "x value is ". $temp ."!"; // Success Message
    }
?>
```

Error Message:

> Notice: Undefined index: x in C:\xampp\htdocs\TeachMoverInterface\ajax.php on line 2

The PHP $_POST array appears to be empty.

Possibly Helpful Browser Debugging Info:

[image]

[image]

As I said, I have been looking at forums for the past week, so some of the actions I tried in order to fix the problem have been to change formatting, change cache and async attributes in the ajax method, substitute the ajax call with a $.post call or XMLHttpRequest, replacing the JavaScript variable with a number in the ajax call, and some other methods I have forgotten.

Comment: If the `$_POST` array is empty, how are you getting the message shown in your screen-shot (i.e. "x value is...")?

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump()` the `$_POST` variable at the start there? I'm wondering if 0.00684... is being rounded to zero and subsequently "falsy" in your `empty()` check.

Comment: What does the request to the server look like when that error occurs? You are showing a successful call.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any other errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @JeremyHarris If I var_dump() the $_POST variable, the output is array(0) { } .

Comment: @epascarello As far as I can tell, the POST requests to the server are sending the joystick coordinate, but the server never receives that data. This problem has happened not just with my code, but other AJAX/PHP code samples I have tried that others have written. I'm not sure if that answers your question, but the server requests that I've seen from the browser consoles seem correct, but the server-side PHP code never seems to respond to the requests.

Comment: Than how are you getting back a response?

Comment: @JayBlanchard The request/response I've looked at is what I've screenshotted and included in my question (using FireBug and the Chrome console). It hasn't really helped me because it seems like the data is being sent but the PHP code never seems to receive it. If you have any better advice on how to use this information to debug, let me know. I have included the jQuery library. It is in my interface.html file. There are no errors other than the Undefined Index warning. I am running this on an Apache server using XAMPP.

Comment: You're getting a response back, that is what the preview is.

Comment: @epascarello I just noticed that on the Chrome console I am indeed getting a response. Does that mean the server is receiving the data, and the problem is that I'm trying to access the ajax.php file directly from the browser?

Comment: @JayBlanchard As I just wrote to epascarello above, does this indicate that the server has been receiving the data and the problem is that I've been trying to access the PHP file's data directly from the browser?

Comment: To everyone who mentioned the response shown in my screenshot, I would be interested in knowing why the PHP code does not echo the data successfully if the server is receiving the data successfully. Thank you!

Comment: If you load the ajax.php directly the `$_POST` array is not set and therefore, undefined. You must send variables to ajax.php (via POST) as you are doing with your AJAX calls.

Comment: @JayBlanchard So to make sure I'm understanding correctly, the reason I am not able to view the echo statement directly is because if I load the file straight from the browser, it is separate from the index.php (and javascript file) and therefore is not receiving data via POST? Sorry if I am completely off, I did not know anything about web development or AJAX until a week ago and am still very much learning. I appreciate your help!

Comment: That is correct @Gopika. `$_POST` is an array which gets populated when you send data to a page (in this case ajax.php) from any other page capable of sending the request. You're using the AJAX call in joystick.js to send the data. Likely what you need to do is create a page into which joystick.js is loaded. That page will make the POST requests to ajax.php to return the values.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks so much! I do have one last question, if you have time. If I were to use the approach you mentioned, how would I retrieve the data from ajax.php to the created page (the one that loads joystick.js file)? You mentioned making a POST request. I know there is an HTTPRequest class for this purpose or I could create a session, but I do not know if I am overthinking it and there is a simper away. Again, thank you for all your help.

Comment: jQuery returns data from the page in the success function here `success: function(data) ` and the variable `data` has the information returned from the PHP page.

Comment: @Gopika One side note here -- using AJAX requests to send a joystick position is going to be horribly laggy if you are making a game as HTTP requests have a large overhead in general. You should probably look at using web sockets to make a single socket connection and then pipe the controller position to the server in real time.

Comment: @JayBlanchard In my case, what would the data parameter contain? Would it contain the echo output? I followed your advice and created another PHP page which loads the joystick.js file, but I have not been able to output the data returned (I tried outputting it via html and alerts). I guess the problem is I am still confused as to the nature of the data parameter in my application and how I would go about outputting it.

Comment: @JeremyHarris Thanks for pointing that out. I am actually using it for a telecontrol application in which the server would control a robotic arm based on the coordinates it receives from the client through a web interface. I am concerned about latency, so I will keep this in mind.

Comment: Yes - it would contain the echo output from PHP. [Read this](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html). Ditto what @JeremyHarris said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As several people have pointed out, my screenshot of the Google Chrome console shows that the ajax.php file is receiving the data sent by the ajax call. My mistake was that I believed accessing the ajax.php file directly should output the data, however as Jay Blanchard pointed out that was an incorrect approach. Thank you for everyone who pointed out my mistake. Also, thanks to Jeremy Harris for mentioning an alternative to AJAX that may be better suited for my application in terms of time performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $temp = $_POST['x'];
    if(isset($temp) && !empty($temp))
    {
        echo "x value is ". $temp ."!"; // Success Message
    }
}
?>
```

modify your ajax.php code

Comment: This may prevent the "Undefined index" error by checking for an empty array first, but it does not explain the problem or why the `$_POST` array is empty.

Answer (score -1):

Change data: {x:x_value}, into data: {"x":x_value},

Comment: I think `x` should still work fine without quotes (even though not technically correct per ECMAScript standards) since it is not a reserved word.

Comment: That is 100% the same